# How to disable columnDefinition to be executed twice in Spring Boot 3.1.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here is a simple entity with a `columnDefinition` property:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "simple_user")
public class SimpleUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(64) NOT NULL default 'John'")
    private String nickname;
}
```

After the first run, a table is created like this:

```
2023-06-24 18:22:20.380 | INFO  | restartedMain | p6spy | 21 ms | statement | create table simple_user (id serial not null, nickname varchar(64) NOT NULL default 'John', primary key (id)) | logSQL(Slf4JLogger.java:60)
2023-06-24 18:22:20.383 | INFO  | restartedMain | p6spy | 2 ms | statement | comment on table simple_user is 'User' | logSQL(Slf4JLogger.java:60)
2023-06-24 18:22:20.387 | INFO  | restartedMain | p6spy | 2 ms | statement | comment on column simple_user.nickname is 'nickname' | logSQL(Slf4JLogger.java:60)
```

After the second run without any modification I get some errors:

```java
2023-06-24 18:25:25.520 | INFO  | restartedMain | c.z.h.HikariDataSource | HikariPool-1 - Start completed. | getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:123)
2023-06-24 18:25:26.079 | INFO  | restartedMain | p6spy | 22 ms | statement | select * from information_schema.sequences | logSQL(Slf4JLogger.java:60)
2023-06-24 18:25:26.106 | INFO  | restartedMain | o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator | HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy | buildBytecodeProvider(BytecodeProviderInitiator.java:53)
2023-06-24 18:25:27.239 | INFO  | restartedMain | o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator | HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform] | initiateService(JtaPlatformInitiator.java:51)
2023-06-24 18:25:27.272 | INFO  | restartedMain | p6spy | 3 ms | statement | select * from information_schema.sequences | logSQL(Slf4JLogger.java:60)
2023-06-24 18:25:27.315 | INFO  | restartedMain | p6spy | 5 ms | statement | alter table if exists simple_user alter column nickname set data type varchar(64) NOT NULL default 'John' | logSQL(Slf4JLogger.java:60)
2023-06-24 18:25:27.317 | WARN  | restartedMain | o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl | GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists simple_user alter column nickname set data type varchar(64) NOT NULL default 'John'" via JDBC [ERROR: syntax error at or near "NOT"
  Position: 83] | handleException(ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl.java:27)
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists simple_user alter column nickname set data type varchar(64) NOT NULL default 'John'" via JDBC [ERROR: syntax error at or near "NOT"
  Position: 83]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:574)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:514)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:333)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:232)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:117)
```

It seems the columnDefinition has been executed again.
This behavior only happened in Spring Boot 3.1.1.

Everything is ok in Spring Boot 3.0.x and 2.6.x.

So, is this a bug or a design?

Comment: I think this is likely to be a Hibernate bug/behavior change. You may want to search https://hibernate.atlassian.net/ for existing issues or try different versions of Hibernate to see if it changes the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(64)", nullable = false)
@ColumnDefault("'John'")
```